# username and password cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: jsp-tags

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        Connection c=null;

        request.getParameter("source");
        request.getParameter("destination");
        request.getParameter("class");        
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try{
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            c= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;instanceName=sqlexpress;databaseName=vacation;selectMethod=cursor","","");
            c.username = "sa";
            c.password = "kassa@123";
            c.createStatement();
```

I am trying to test jsp model! https://i.stack.imgur.com/5blfT.png with rspec but I am facing error how to solve this error please give me some idea.

Comment: Please post your code instead of uploading screenshots. This makes it easier for others when searching for similar problems.

Comment: i get alert box like this "You need at least 10 reputation to post images"   thatswhy i put link

Comment: Please re-read my comment @karthik bala ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the connection in the wrongway. 
Use the following method instead to retrieve connection

```
getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;instanceName=sqlexpress;databaseName=vacation;selectMethod=cursor", 
"sa", "kassa@123")
```

The following wont work because they are not accessible in the connection publicly. (Fields are always private.)

```
  c.username = "sa";
  c.password = "kassa@123";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how the method definition looks like -

```
public static Connection getConnection(String url,
                   String user,
                   String password)
```

It is very strange how you are doing. Providing user and password as "" (empty string) in the above method and then trying to access these private variable?